# Blender 2.80 fix normals after boolean

Tags: modifiers, normals

[image]Hello, I am looking for help in solving my problem, I used Boolean for my tire, the result is visible in the picture, I have been doing the tire 5 times and I have the same effect all the time, please help:(

I use after boolean:
-autosmooth
-cleanup losses
-triangles
-quads
-copy normal to selected from stock tube object
-shade smooth

[image]

Comment: hello, your question is very vague, could you point out the exact problem? Maybe share the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: hello I upload file:) I dont know where i fail with this modifer... Can You help me with this i need understand what im doing wrong for now and future:)

Comment: I see ngons everywhere, so maybe keep only one section of your tire, delete the rest, work your section until it's clean, meaning nice topology with only quads (there are a lot of tire tutorials by the way), then give it an array with an empty object so that your section is repeated all around

Comment: Moonboots Thank You very mutch You are great :) this solve my problem:) i see sometime i cant create other topology but after this i can fix this:))

Answer (score 1):

Your topology is bad, you have a lot of ngons, you need quads. What you could do is correct your object this way:

- Apply the rotation of your object. Only keep a section, delete the rest:

[image]

- Create an empty at the origin of your object:

[image]

- Give your object an *Array* modifier with the empty as *Offset Object*. Enable *Merge* and *First Last* options:

[image]

- Rotate your object so that it makes a complete circle:

[image]

- Correct your topology with the knife or with some joins so that it is made of nice quads, create some bevels, etc (here just the beginning before my computer crashed):

[image]